# AWS DMS connection error ("password authentication failed")

Tags: amazon-web-services

I configured source and target endpoint for DMS services, both of them are postgresDB one on EC2 machine, one on RDS.

When I test connection on both of them, I got the following error:

> Operation:testEndpointDetails:[errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=122500, errMessage=Cannot connect to ODBC provider [122500] ODBC unkown error., errDetails= RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 28P01 NativeError: 210 Message: [unixODBC]FATAL: password authentication failed for user "docker" [122502] ODBC general error.]

What does that mean ? How could I possibly debug this ?

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? I am seeing the exact same thing pointing to two Posgtres DBs, both on RDS.

Answer (score 0):

you need to grant permission to user docker and / or use correct password when you defined the endpoints.